# Intermittent error with include_once on shared php files

Tags: php, apache

I have run into an annoying issue that seems to be popping up intermittently across my applications.

These applications live in `/data/www/directory` which is the php document root. All of these applications need to access a shared php file for SSO authentication which lives in `/usr/share/php`.

Even if I change the location of the file to `/data/new/path`, it will still fail.

When a file uses `include_once "SSO.php";`, it will **sometimes** fail, resulting in the following message:

`Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/usr/share/php/SSO.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /data/www/directory/path/to/index.php on line 2`

I am using the default include_path in the apache2 php.ini which is where `SSO.php` lives.

The weird thing about this issue, is that if I open the file with file_get_contents(), I can var_dump the contents onto the screen. Example:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('/usr/share/php/SSO.php'));
```

In the example I know that I'm using an absolute path. I have also tried to use include_once with the absolute path to the shared php file with the same error resulting.

Any suggestions would be excellent!

Comment: `include_path` is irrelevant when using an absolute path.

Comment: @Barmar, I know that they are unrelated, but I have tried both solutions.

Comment: Check the error message before that, it should contain the OS error message after `failed to open stream:`

Comment: Something like this: `Warning: include_once(/usr/share/php/SSO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: In the logs, what seems to be the SSO.php file I see. `PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/usr/share/php/SSO.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') `

Comment: It doesn't show the path for the SSO file in the include_once()?

Comment: When I try to include a nonexistent file I get two warning mesages. The first one starts with `include_once(filename)` and the second starts with `include_once():`. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled.

Comment: Hm, even after setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, I'm still only getting the warning I showed above.

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: I tested this with both 5.6 and 7.3, I get both error messages. I don't know why you're only getting the second one. The first message contains the useful details.

Comment: From phpinfo(): `PHP Version 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`